# JS Multiple image upload width validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, image-uploading

I have a multiple file upload field for images that I want to validate each image's width before upload to ensure it's less than 640px.

If one of the images is larger, preferably I would have it removed from the FileList before the rest of the images are uploaded. Reading a bit around tells me this is not possible because FileList is read only? (Possible workaround would be to make a separate array, but I'm using Rails with gem s3_direct_upload which builds upon jquery-fileupload, so I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that).

Therefore at least I would like to clear the FileList and alert the user so that he can select all the images another time without the images that were too large.

My problem is that I'm looping through all the images getting the width with FileReader and image.onload (which is async?), and since the invalid image(s) could be anywhere in the loop, I haven't been able to figure out a proper way to flag one or more of the images as invalid, wait for the loop to finish completely before handling the result. Setting 'validated' after the image has been loaded and the width is known does not seem to work since it's async hence the method always returns true.

Here's my code:

```
$('#fileUploadField').change(function (e) {
  if (window.FileReader) {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var images = this.files;
      if(images && images[0]) {
        for (var i=0 ; i < images.length; i++) {
          var validated = validateImg(images[i]);
          if (validated = false) {
           //...do something
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
});

function validateImg(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader(),
      image = new Image(),
      validated = true;

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  image.src = _file.target.result;
  reader.onload = function(_file) {
    image.onload = function() {
        var w = this.width,
            n = file.name;
      if (w > 640) {
        validated = false;
      } else {
        $('.imgs-preview-wrap').append('<img src="'+ image.src +'">');
      }
    };
  };
  return validated;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do as follows. Make the `upload` button `disabled` by default. When an image is added, make it `disabled`, check the width and either leave the new image or remove it (mark it as invalid). After that `enable` the `upload` button. This way when the `upload` button is `enabled`, you will know that all the images are ok for upload.

Comment: Not sure how this would work with my current setup. Like I explained in my question, it's a multiple file upload field, so user can choose several images at once. Secondly the width is only known after the image(s) have been "read", which is async, so currently I don't know when all images have been read/validated...

Comment: My understanding is that you need to allow the user to only upload images that have some characteristics. You check that asynchronously. My suggestion is to forbid the upload while the validation takes place. That is when the images to be validated are selected, but you still do not know if they are valid. After the validation you filter them and allow the user to upload them.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to help Ivaylo, I appreciate it ;) The upload is already performed at a later time, it's not connected to the validation. But what I'm having problems with is to know when all the images have been checked, and at that time perform a function...

Comment: If the problem is how to know that it is safe to `enable` the `upload` button, i.e. know that all the validations are ready, I would do the following. I will pass an object to the `validateImg` function that contains a map between images and validation results. When the validation is finished for a given image, this object will be modified. When the size of this map is equal to the number of images to be validated, I will perform the final action. I will perform the size check in the end of each image validation. As JS is supposed to be single-threaded, everything should work...

Comment: Thanks. I will try this approach and see how it goes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not good. Javascript is insecure. Use PHP instead or any other server-side language.

Comment: I agree that he should not rely only on JS, but I guess his goal is to reduce the load of the server by skipping the upload of images that will be deleted on the server.

Comment: Yeah like Ivaylo says I'm trying to upload directly to Amazon S3 with JS in order to avoid the request ever hitting our server, so server side validation is out of the question.

This is for an internal control panel / CRM, so it's unlikely the user will try to circumvent the client side validation ;)